# How to capture audit history on ActiveRecord tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, audit

I would like to turn on audit history of all changes which happens on certain tables exposed as `ActiveRecord` interfaces. Are there any gems which can enable this functionality?

```
create table foo (id, field1, field2, field3 ...)
```

It should be possible to create an audit on all field transitions either on creation | updation.

```
e.g. field 1  transitioned from value1 --> value11
e.g. field 2  transitioned from value2 --> value22
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Ruby Toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/) is the place to go for the choices and these are [your choices for ActiveRecord audit](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Active_Record_Versioning) gems

Answer (score 2):

Try https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited , this is an ORM extension. and seems to be the best